# Reference operator in function name during declaration

Tags: c++

I understand that this

```
double grade(int &hw) {}
```

is passing an argument by reference. And that this

```
double a;
double &b = a;
```

is making b a reference to a.

But what about this

```
istream &read_hw(istream &in) {}
```

What does the reference operator before the name of the function signify, and in what cases would the effect be desired?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the type of the return value. In that case, a `istream &` is returned, so a reference to an istream object.

This is desired if the returned value is meant to be modified by the caller. E.g. you can return a reference to an member variable to make it modifyable

```
class X {
private:
  int i_;
public:
  int &i() {return i_;}
  const int &i() const {return i_;}
};
```

In such a case, the member `i()` can be used as getter and setter:

```
X x;
int a = x.i();
x.i() = 10;
```

In the your case of iostreams, the method returns a reference to the passed-in istream object, to enable chaining, e.g. like `cout << a << b << c`, which calls 3 times
`ostream &operator << (ostream &, <whatever>)`

Answer (score 2):

It's basically the same thing: the function `read_hw()` returns a reference to an `istream` instance.

It's generally used to return either the object itself (`*this`), or one of the method's arguments (`in` here), and avoid the superfluous temporary object creation that can occur when returning by value.

Comment: But why return a reference? Why return anything? It was passed a reference to an istream, why not modify the istream and return void? In other words, why return something we've already modified? I can think of a few cases where returning the istream would be useful, but why return a reference to it and not just the value?

Comment: Well, it's a design decision, so it can be argued upon, but one of the benefits is that it allows *chaining*: if a method `foo()` returns the object it's called on, several calls can be made in succession by issuing something like `obj.foo("bar").foo("quux");`. That would be equivalent to `obj.foo("bar"); obj.foo("quux");`.